# OpenCV 3.0: Error Aruco.hpp no such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem,i am working on the raspberry PI with OPenCV 3.0+Aruco. I have installed openCV 3.0 and also the openCV_contrib, with a correct process of installation and build. But when i try to compile a project that is detect_board.cpp that is placed in the opencv_contrib i get the following error:
aruco.hpp is not a file or directory.
But the file aruco.hpp is there. It is in the opencv_contrib-master/modules/aruco/include/opencv2. The header file that are included in the program are:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: But are you sure the the aruco.hpp is installed in your system somewhere /usr/loca/... (or wherever) and you are passing a valid "-I" option to include the directorie where it's located? (I'm assuming you are using gcc)

Comment: It should be found in `<OPENCV_DIR>/install/include/opencv2`, not in `master/modules/etc...`

Comment: You should build OpenCV with contrib modules, not build OpenCV and then add contrib modules.

Comment: So i explain you what i have done. First i have installed the OpenCv,creating the build directory, and using the cmake and after make. After i have download the opencv_contrib and extract it, inside the build directory and after i have excuted the instruction in the opencv_contrib section. Now the only file aruco.hpp is inside the directory OPencv/build/opencv_contrib/modules/include/opencv2. For example the highgui.hpp file is inside the directory Opencv/modules/highgui/include/opencv2 and not inside the directory build/modules.

Comment: Steps to compile using Mac here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058527/cmake-compling-opencv-3-2-0-error

Answer (score 2):

it seems u don't have openCV 3.1.- installed!
aruco is an extra module for openCV3 ... 
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d6d/tutorial_table_of_content_aruco.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

just run cmake gui on aruco folder in opencv_contrib-master by creating a build folder inside it, and then open terminal at the folder location and  sudo make install. this works for single module installation from contrib-master .