# Cmake Compling OpenCv 3.2.0 error

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, compilation

following this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/), no matter what configuration i try it always fails?

This is my Cmake command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules     \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/bin/python     \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON    \
-D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so    \
-D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR= /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/    \
-D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ ..
```

Here is the Cmake output

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- FP16: Feature disabled
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found TIFF: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.9") 
-- Found JPEG: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libjpeg.so  
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1") 
-- Found ZLIB: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34") 
-- Looking for /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/include/libpng/png.h - not found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION - Failed
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   Found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.30
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.48.2
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
--   Found libavcodec, version 56.60.100
--   Found libavformat, version 56.40.101
--   Found libavutil, version 54.31.100
--   Found libswscale, version 3.1.101
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz to /home/kamarol/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/kamarol/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/bin/python (found suitable version "3.6.4", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.4", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (found suitable exact version "3.6.4") 
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   YES
-- Glog:   NO
-- Checking for one of the modules 'freetype2'
-- Checking for one of the modules 'harfbuzz'
-- freetype2:   YES
-- harfbuzz:    YES
-- Found HDF5: /home/kamarol/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/home/kamarol/anaconda3/lib/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so (found version "1.10.1") 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF - Success
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Failed
-- libprotobuf: Unpacking v3.1.0/protobuf-cpp-3.1.0.tar.gz to /home/kamarol/opencv/build/modules/dnn/3rdparty/protobuf/sources...
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE - Success
-- freetype2:   YES
-- harfbuzz:    YES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Checking for modules 'tesseract;lept'
--   Found tesseract, version 3.04.01
--   Found lept, version 1.73
-- Tesseract:   YES
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_48.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_64.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_80.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_120.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_bi.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_hd.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_064.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_128.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_256.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_lbgm.i ...
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD - Failed
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               3.2.0
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/kamarol/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3.2.0
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2018-01-02T16:37:38Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libpng.so /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libz.so /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libjpeg.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 fontconfig freetype gthread-2.0 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg /home/kamarol/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /home/kamarol/anaconda3/lib/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so tesseract lept dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp IlmImf libprotobuf
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn freetype fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow phase_unwrapping stitching structured_light python3
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 viz cnn_3dobj cvv matlab sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.30)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/kamarol/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/kamarol/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.4)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.6.4)
--     numpy:                       /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.6/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/kamarol/.conda/envs/pyparkenv1/bin/python3
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/kamarol/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kamarol/opencv/build
```

And [the output](https://pastebin.com/D9ptKXXs) when i run *make -j8*

At first i used opencv3.4.0 but that didn't work as well, so i used an older version such as in the tutorial, but same compilation error. I did install tesseract libraries as well.

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4
Python: 3.6
OpenCV: 3.2.0
OpenCV_Contrib: 3.2.0
```

Comment: It is always better if you post the errror in your post and not in the link... Anyways, I would recommend to use ccmake and make sure the the use_tiff variable is ON... not always is ON even if it was found

Comment: Looks like you are missing libtiff.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it compiled and working on MacOS with contrib modules mostly based on instructions from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/#build-step).

Assuming you are in /Users/chris/P/opencv

```
brew install pkg-config
git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv_contrib.git
git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
```

Then this command didn't work for me.

`cmake -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/chris/P/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules`

So I opened [cmake gui](https://cmake.org/download/) and set the above params using it. Configure & Generate.
[image]

Then goto the build folder `/Users/chris/P/opencv/opencv/build` and run

```
make
make install
cp  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv3.pc
```

Now finally to test it

```
cd /Users/chris/P/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/samples
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv3` detect_markers.cpp -o /tmp/detect_markers
/tmp/detect_markers
```